# Are dilation and rotation the same thing in Mobius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Speaking of Möbius transformation, I think a rotation counter-clockwise by $\theta$ is actually a dilation by a magnitude of $e^{-i\theta}$. Is this correct?

Comment: dilatations and rotations both are [homotheties/similarities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Decomposition_and_elementary_properties) hence of the form $z \to a z +b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually you use the words "dilation" and "rotation" to speak about the transformation from a geometric point of view (they are different geometric transformations).
2. Actualy multiplying by $e^{i\theta}$ produces a counter-clockwise rotation by $\theta$ radiants.